# Android DateUtils.format inconsistant with Calendar.get field in Russia

Tags: android, datetime-format

Android 4.4.2

Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) return wrong value in Russia.

I created a small test that shows the problem. If I change my phone to Moscow time zone it is not reproduced, but for user in Moscow it does.

I am using the below code to format a date:

```
DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR);
```

And the below code to get calendar field values:

```
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

The problem for the test I did was that:
- The hours when using the DateUtils.format was 11
- The hours when using the calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) was 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my solution here in case anyone else will have this problem:

I found out that the problem is with the DateUtils, it does not format the time correctly (even if I explicitly pass the TimeZone).

I converted the use of DateUtils to SimpleDateFormat and it solved the problem.

I needed to do some manipulation in order to get the date\time format that I needed, but the end result was the same as using DateUtils.